# What's the error in 'for' loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why do the following raise an error?

```
for(; 0   ;)     System.out.println("guess");  // or
for(;false;)     System.out.println("guess");  // or
for(; 1   ;)     System.out.println("guess");
```

But the following runs okay (infinitely):

```
for(;true;)      System.out.println("guess");
```

Why does it work for `true` but not for `false`?

Comment: `;true;` is always true and is a valid condition. `false` will never be true, so is invalid. The rest are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: ``for(;;)`` does work as an infinite loop, too

Comment: @AliAkber I would recommend reading up on for-loops (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). As it states:

`When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates`

So your loop won't even execute because it's already terminated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *condition* (i.e. the bit between the `;`s) must be a boolean, so this immediately rules out the first and third variants in your first snippet.

Now, the second variant, in which you *have* used a boolean, doesn't compile because the compiler realizes that the loop will never be entered and hence issues an error:

```
Untitled.java:3: error: unreachable statement
        for(;false;)     System.out.println("guess");
                         ^
1 error
```

---

Note that the JLS mandates that errors be issued for unreachable statements (see [§14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)):

> **It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.**
>
> ...
>
> The contained statement is reachable iff the `for` statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is `false`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's debatable. I would have probably made it a warning if I were designing the compiler, but I'm sure there's a case to be made for making it an error as well.

Comment: Is `;false;` an error in Java? Just tested in C# and it compiles fine, but it does provide a warning that the code inside is unreachable (which is obvious).

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yes it's an error in Java, probably due to constant propagation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's my guess. Seems smart for it to be an error with it being completely useless anyway.

Comment: Hmmm. This is a violation of JLS then, right? Compiles fine: `if(false) System.out.println("jls sucks!");` Also this works too: `for(boolean b = false; b; b= false) System.out.println("What  stupid rule!");`

Comment: @Dima That one specific case is handled differently, as described at the very end of the JLS section I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @dima Make `b` `final`.

Comment: Yeah ... I don't know what these people where smoking when they wrote this. `if(DEBUG)` is useful, but `while(DEBUG)` is somehow not ... Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Java requires a boolean as second parameter in your loop header, it evaluates the statement and if the statement returns true the jvm will run the code of the loop-body, not the body will be skipped.

0 and 1 are obviously no booleans nor do they define a statement which could be evaluated (like x < y) and since java is a static and strong typed language (unlike Python or Perl) it cannot cast an int to a boolean, so it crashes.

Edit: If you provide "false" as statement the JVM will notice that the loop-body never can be reached, this will cause a runtime-error.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C, in Java, `true` and `false` correspond to `boolean` type values, where 1 and 0 to `int` (in fact, in C there is no `boolean` declarative type, and boolean checks are done based on integer comparisons. In Java, things are distinct).